# Create Copy clipboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to make a clone of node to get the UID encrypting the data into the clipboard. I got the id from the internal server but I don't know how to clone the node so it understands the correct location it copied.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper" id="form-inf">
        <h3>Information</h3>
        <a href="../form_inf_sv/index.php" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Import UID</a>
        <a href="./index.php" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button">Select</a>
        <table style="width:100%" class="form-main-table">
            <tr>
                <th>STT</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>UID</th>
                <th>Day Create</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                require '../connect/connect.php';   
                // $sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
                $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_new_uid WHERE cd_del=1";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                  echo "";
                } else {
                  echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_new_uid ORDER BY date_create DESC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
                $stt = 1; 
                while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){ 
                    ?>              
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$stt++?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
                        <td id="inf_copy"><?=$row['uid_new']?></td>
                        <td><?=$row['date_create']?></td>
                        <td><a href='#' class="btn btn-info" style="width: 100px;">Edit</a>
                        <a href='./config/delete.php/?id=<?=$row['id']?>' class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100px;">Delete</a>
                        <button id="btn_copy" class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 100px;">Copy</button></td>
                    </tr>   
            <?php   }
                $conn->close();
            ?> 
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    // setTimeout('window.location.reload();',3000);
</script>
<script>
    $('#btn_copy').on('click', function() {
    var text = $('#inf_copy').html();
    var tempElement = $('<input>').val(text).appendTo('body').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    tempElement.remove();
    var elem = document.getElementById("inf_copy");
        elem.style.background = "yellow";
        elem.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: IDs need to be unique. you can use `this` from an event to get the relative elements, eg: `var text = $('#inf_copy', this.parentNode.parentNode).text();` you might need to change that to a class to get it to work in some versions of jq.

Answer (score 0):

- Update id for "td" tag, that you want to copy text from
- Update Button "id" As id must have to be uniqe
- Updated Coding Lines are as bellow

HTML CODE UPDATE

```
<td id="inf_copy_<?php echo $row['uid_new']; ?>"><?=$row['uid_new']?></td>

<td><a href='#' class="btn btn-info" style="width: 100px;">Edit</a>
      <a href='./config/delete.php/?id=<?=$row['id']?>' class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100px;">Delete</a>
<button id="btn_copy_<?php echo $row['uid_new']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn_copy" style="width: 100px;">Copy</button>
  </td>
```

JS CODE UPDATE

```
$('.btn_copy').on('click', function() {
    var btn_copy = this.id;
    btn_copy = btn_copy.replace('btn_','inf_');
    var text = $('#'+btn_copy).html();
```